# Codeigniter : issue with login function

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am trying to write basic login functionality like as below .

**Controller**

```
public function  submit_login(){
            if($this->input->post('submit')){
                $email= $this->input->post('email');
                $password= $this->input->post('password');
                $this->load->model('user_model');
                $result= $this->user_model->login($email, $password);

            }
        }
```

**Model**

```
public function login($email, $password){
        $this->db->select('email', 'password');
        $this->db->where('email',$email); 
        $this->db->where('password',$password);
        $this->db-> limit(1);
        $query= $this->db->get('user');

        if($query->num_rows()>0){
            return $query->result();
        }
        return false ; 

    }
```

Now problem is that its not returning what i expect it to do , its going to else statement , all the posted field values and database values are same so please help me to fix this problem

Comment: Does it make it to the user login method in the model, or does it only get the submit_login() method in the controller? If it gets to the model, what  values do you get from $query->num_rows() and $query->result().

Comment: i have a login controller that has array for form , then it is submitted to submit_login and data is passed to login method , in login it returns false  thats what heppening

Comment: What version Codeigniter? What is output if you `var_dump($query->num_rows());`

Comment: prints nothing, 2.

Comment: If you dump it `$query= $this->db->get('user'); var_dump($query->num_rows());` there ... it prints nothing? If that's the case it sounds like it may not even be getting to that point. Put some echo statements through out the path and see which ones print out and see if you find where the script it stopping.

Comment: Your method do nothing. Put `var_dump($result)` in last line of method.

Answer (score 1):

Change in your model as below

```
$this->db->select('email, password');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code, it may help:

**Controller**

```
public function  submit_login(){
        if($this->input->post('submit')){
            $email= $this->input->post('email');
            $password= $this->input->post('password');
            $this->load->model('user_model');
            $result= $this->user_model->login($email);
            if(!empty($result))
            {
               if($result->password == $password)
               {
                    ////do something
               }
               else
                {
                   // print error
                }

            }
            else
            {
            // do something
            }
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
public function login($email){
    $this->db->select('password');
    $this->db->where('email',$email); 

    $query= $this->db->get('user');
    return $query->row();
 }
```